# JPQL like expression requires int value

Tags: java, expression, jpql, sql-like

I'd like to search a requested value in my database using the entity manager createquery function. Whenever I executed my method, I got the following error message:

> llegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String for parameter searchvalue with expected type of int from query string

It says that a int value is required, but I think that every like expression requires a string value?

Entity:

```
public class Contract implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "number")
    private int number;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "minimum_term")
    private int minimumTerm;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "cancellation_period")
    private int cancelTime;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Users userId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Supplier supplierId;

    [...]
}
```

QueryString:

```
List mylist = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Contract c WHERE c.userId = :userid AND (c.number LIKE :search OR c.type LIKE :search OR c.description LIKE :search OR c.startDate LIKE :search OR c.supplierId.name LIKE :search OR c.cancelTime LIKE :search OR c.minimumTerm LIKE :search)", Contract.class)
    .setParameter("userid", user).setParameter("search", "%"+search+"%")
    .getResultList()
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andrei Nicusan stated you cannot us LIKE operator on an int.

You can cast the value to string and use in the where clause :

1. Use a native query and use [MySQL cast function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).
2. Use your JPA provider for extension function, if your using Hibernate you can use also use CAST (type as string). See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for your `number` column, it is very normal to expect an integer as parameter because this is an integer-typed column. You can't compare or match numerical values with strings.

Second, `LIKE` clauses can only be applied to strings. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvg).

Comment: Is there any other way? In MySQL, for example, I can search with the like expression for Strings even though the column is integer.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from **int** to **string** in JPQL you can use **CAST**

HERE are an example (NOTE: Assuming MyEntity has id with type int)

```
public List<MyEntity> getMyEntities(String idStr) {
   return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MyEntity m WHERE CAST( m.id AS string ) LIKE :idStr")
         .setParameter("idStr", "%" + idStr+ "%").getResultList();
}
```

I am using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate provider.

I tested it and this previous code working fine with me, so i hope it can help some one :)