# convert BigDecimal to String in order to filter some BigDecimal ids using LIKE in JPQL query

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I want to filter BigDecimal ids using LIKE keyword in JPQL. I use EclipseLink.

Let say we have ids: 197718, 182123, 182912, 123456 and I want to extract all rows from the table where the entity.id like %18%. If the operation would be successful, the result would be: **182123, 182912**.

My query would be.

```
public List<MyEntity> getFilteredMyEntity(String idStr) {
   return entityManager.createQuery("select m from MyEntity m where m.id like :idStr")
                       .query.setParameter("idStr", "%" + idStr+ "%")
                       .getResultList();
}
```

Let say I call this method this way in order to get all entities that contains "18" in the id:

```
List<MyEntity> entities = getFilteredMyEntity("18");
```

But I get an exception because I can't compare a BigDecimal with a String. So, I have to convert this BigDecimal to String

Is there a way in jpql (not native query) to convert BigDecimal to String? Something like to_char().

Comment: `String#valueOf` and `BigDecimal#toString` seem like obvious choices. Those didn't work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPQL like expression requires int value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22558476/5221149) or [JPA Like Operator with Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5535084/5221149). Both say same thing: Cast/convert `m.id` to string in query text, so `like` has string on both sides.

Comment: pls check my answer, i tested it using JPQL and it's working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in **JPQL** like next (i tested it my side and it worked with me)

> **Note:** i am using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate provider

```
public List<MyEntity> getFilteredMyEntity(String idStr) {
   return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MyEntity m WHERE CAST( m.id AS string ) LIKE :idStr")
         .setParameter("idStr", "%" + idStr+ "%").getResultList();
}
```

**And** here are another way using **native query**

```
public List<MyEntity> getFilteredMyEntity(String idStr) {
   return entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT m FROM MyEntity m WHERE CAST(m.id AS varchar(10)) LIKE :idStr")
         .setParameter("idStr", "%" + idStr+ "%").getResultList();
}
```

Comment: @NellyJunior i noted that i am using hibernate with JPA, and actually i tested it, but also didn't tests it with any other provider, anyway you can edit in my answer in the way you see it will help any one in the future and i will check your edits, Thanks :)